# req.session not updating in node JS ---> express-session

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

iam using express-session and memcache

```
 let sessionConfigValues = {
        resave: false,
        rolling: true,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        secret: sessionConfig.secretKey,
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 900000
        },
        store: memcacheStore
    }
```

```
if (userInfoQry != null) {
dbRPool.query(userInfoQry, function (orgErr, orgData)
- {
if ((orgErr || orgData.length == 0))
 { 
utils.log(utils.LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "Failed to get org info , Err : " + stringifyError(orgErr)); callback(err, null); 
}
 else {
 let obj = orgData[0] 
if (!isAdmin) { 
let { name, org_name, time_created, start_date, live_date } = obj;

req.session.userOrgName = !org_name ? name : org_name;
req.session.timeCreated = time_created;
req.session.liveDate = live_date;
req.session.userBillingStartDate = start_date;

**console.log(req.session.userBillingStartDate) // getting value here**
}
obj.email = email
callback(null, obj);
};
});
 }

**consoling outside 
console.log(req.session.userBillingStartDate) // undefined**
```

session value for userBillingDate should be updated but getting as undefined.

unable to log outside function.

Thanks in advance